# What does local_root mean in vsftpd?

Tags: vsftpd

The local_root setting in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is as below:

```
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
```

Now connect my vps with sftp:

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/ftpuser
sftp> ls  /home/$USER/ftp
Can't ls: "/home/$USER/ftp" not found
```

In manual:local_root,this option represents a directory which vsftpd will try to change into after a local (i.e. non-anonymous) login. Failure is silently ignored.

Why "/home/$USER/ftp" not found when to login with a local non-anonymous (ftpuser is an account in vsftpd)?